# Users are redirected to homepage instead of wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, login

After migrating my wordpress site users **who are not Admins** are redirected to the site's **homepage after login**. On the old site they were redirected on wp-admin. The Administrator is redirected to wp_admin as it should.

I want the users to be redirected to `wp-admin` after login.

I changed siteurl from the database (`wp_options`), also added this filter in my `functions.php`:

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {


    return admin_url();
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Any help please?
Thank you and Happy Easter!

Comment: You can also use this plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-based-redirect/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeeey, I figured it out! Actually my theme had a redirect like this one in `functions.php`:

```
// Block Access to /wp-admin for non admins.
function custom_blockusers_init() {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_admin() && !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_blockusers_init' ); // Hook into 'init'
```

All you have to do is add your own role capability, for example: `!current_user_can( 'manage-reports' )`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408334/wordpress-admin-ajax-results-in-error-302-redirect) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

@Hello Lili is right. But, we should check DOING_AJAX also!

```
// Block Access to /wp-admin for non admins.
function custom_blockusers_init() {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_admin() && !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && (defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && !DOING_AJAX) ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_blockusers_init' ); // Hook into 'init'
```

Comment: FYI there are one too many closing parentheses in your answer (at the end of the if statement)  Threw me for a few mins.  Thanks though.  This helped me (I *want* to redirect non-admins to the homepage)

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working like expected. This code restricts non admin users to access wp-admin or profile page.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_admin_users' );
/**
 * Redirect non-admin users to home page
 *
 * This function is attached to the 'admin_init' action hook.
 */
function redirect_non_admin_users() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

LAST RESORT THAT WORKS
You can temporarily disable redirection from the wp-login.php file and  then delete all newly installed or updated plugins.

1. Disable redirection by opening the file wp-login.php

2.Scroll down to the line  where you have the code "do_action( "login_form_{$action}" );"
Mine was around line 461

3. Comment out that line of code to disable redirection
4. Save the file. You will now be able to login using http://www.example.com/wp-login.php
5. Disable or delete all recently installed plugins especially plugins that manage access control functionalities
6. Clear your cookies and cache

Comment: It is really bad practice to change wordpress core files